# Want to plot a graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, boxplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
loans.boxplot(columns="RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines")
```

on running the above i am getting the below error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3237ef4a136d> in <module>
----> 1 loans.boxplot(columns="RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, backend, **kwargs)
    492 ):
    493     plot_backend = _get_plot_backend(backend)
--> 494     return plot_backend.boxplot_frame(
    495         self,
    496         column=column,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
    383     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    384 
--> 385     ax = boxplot(
    386         self,
    387         column=column,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py in boxplot(data, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
    362             data = data[columns]
    363 
--> 364         result = plot_group(columns, data.values.T, ax)
    365         ax.grid(grid)
    366 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py in plot_group(keys, values, ax)
    301         keys = [pprint_thing(x) for x in keys]
    302         values = [np.asarray(remove_na_arraylike(v), dtype=object) for v in values]
--> 303         bp = ax.boxplot(values, **kwds)
    304         if fontsize is not None:
    305             ax.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=fontsize)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1446         if data is None:
-> 1447             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1448 
   1449         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

---

### Update

```
loans.boxplot(column="RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines")
```

on running the above i am getting the below error

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) in ----> 1 loans.boxplot(column="RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_core.py in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, backend, **kwargs) 492 ): 493 plot_backend = _get_plot_backend(backend) --> 494 return plot_backend.boxplot_frame( 495 self, 496 column=column,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_matplotlib\boxplot.py in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds) 383 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 384 --> 385 ax = boxplot( 386 self, 387 column=column,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_matplotlib\boxplot.py in boxplot(data, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds) 360 columns = data.columns 361 else: --> 362 data = data[columns] 363 364 result = plot_group(columns, data.values.T, ax)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in getitem(self, key) 3028 if is_iterator(key): 3029 key = list(key) -> 3030 indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1] 3031 3032 # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing) 1264 keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr) 1265 -> 1266 self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing) 1267 return keyarr, indexer 1268

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing) 1306 if missing == len(indexer): 1307 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis) -> 1308 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]") 1309 1310 ax = self.obj._get_axis(axis)

KeyError: "None of [Index(['RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

---

- [Data Sample](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J4dYGQlWKSTIKdll9qE8ehElD9F3S6ec?usp=sharing)

```py
Sr_No,SeriousDlqin2yrs,RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines,age,NumberOfTime30-59DaysPastDueNotWorse,DebtRatio,MonthlyIncome,NumberOfOpenCreditLinesAndLoans,NumberOfTimes90DaysLate,NumberRealEstateLoansOrLines,NumberOfTime60-89DaysPastDueNotWorse,NumberOfDependents
1,1,0.766126609,45,2,0.802982129,9120.0,13,0,6,0,2.0
2,0,0.957151019,40,0,0.121876201,2600.0,4,0,0,0,1.0
3,0,0.65818014,38,1,0.085113375,3042.0,2,1,0,0,0.0
4,0,0.233809776,30,0,0.036049682,3300.0,5,0,0,0,0.0
5,0,0.9072394,49,1,0.024925695,63588.0,7,0,1,0,0.0
6,0,0.213178682,74,0,0.375606969,3500.0,3,0,1,0,1.0
7,0,0.305682465,57,0,5710.0,,8,0,3,0,0.0
8,0,0.754463648,39,0,0.209940017,3500.0,8,0,0,0,0.0
9,0,0.116950644,27,0,46.0,,2,0,0,0,
10,0,0.189169052,57,0,0.606290901,23684.0,9,0,4,0,2.0
11,0,0.644225962,30,0,0.30947621,2500.0,5,0,0,0,0.0
12,0,0.01879812,51,0,0.53152876,6501.0,7,0,2,0,2.0
13,0,0.010351857,46,0,0.298354075,12454.0,13,0,2,0,2.0
14,1,0.964672555,40,3,0.382964747,13700.0,9,3,1,1,2.0
15,0,0.019656581,76,0,477.0,0.0,6,0,1,0,0.0
```

Comment: This is caused by a typo (e.g. `column=`, not `columns=`) and should have been called out in a comment, and flagged as caused by a typo. Do not add answers for issues caused by a typo. SO is not a substitute for reading the documentation [`pandas.DataFrame.boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html): **column: str or list of str, optional**

Comment: Given the sample `csv`, the issue is not reproducible: see [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMPq8.png)

Comment: To OP has provided sufficient information, but after resolving the typo of the first issue, the second issue is not reproducible, as shown in my previous comment. I do not recommend reopening the question.

Comment: Read the data in with `df = pd.read_csv('cs-training.csv')`, You could try specifying the column by column index using `.iloc`: `ax = df.iloc[:, [2]].boxplot(); ax.set_yscale('log')`. However, `ax = df.boxplot(column='RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines'); ax.set_yscale('log')` should work without issue.

Comment: Thanks Trenton for your support.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: I am wondering why my code execution was not working. The code that you gave is working. There's not much difference except that i used instead of 'df', the data frame as 'loans'.

Comment: Are you using a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes i am using Jupyter notebook

Comment: My guess is you somehow overwrote `loans`, or removed a column somehow. Probably best to just restart the kernel and clear all outputs. When you're having these types of issues, check the dataframe with `df.info()` or `loans.info()` depending the the name of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, it seems as if the keyword is "column" https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html

`DataFrame.boxplot(column=None, by=None, ax=None, fontsize=None, rot=0, grid=True, figsize=None, layout=None, return_type=None, backend=None, **kwargs)`

Comment: I changed the name to 'column' still there is a error coming as - KeyError: "None of [Index(['RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: please provide example of your data. You can easily copy it with df.to_clipboard() and then paste it in your question.

Comment: Do not post answers to problems caused by typo type issues, or answer with **your code works**. These issues should be called out in comments and flagged, as there is a specific close flag **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. Please see [How do I handle "it's working" answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348880/7758804). These questions are typically downvoted, closed and deleted, as they are of no benefit to the community.